# MobileFirst 8.0 - Issue integrate Security Check Adapter with javascript HTTP Soap Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

Good Day,

I have modified two adapters, one is with Security Check - UserLogin Adapter, and another one is HttpAdapterJs (Javascript adapter) ,  HttpAdapterJs are work fine when i tested in Swagger (soap service).

when I called the Adapter HttpAdapterJs  from UserLogin Adapter using AdapterAPI its will return null values.

```
HttpUriRequest req = adaptersAPI.createJavascriptAdapterRequest("HTTPAdapterJS", "getAuthenticationService", URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8"),
                    URLEncoder.encode(pass_word);
            org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = adaptersAPI.executeAdapterRequest(req);
```

Then, I read this : [Unable to initialize AdaptersAPI Object in MobileFirst V8.0 adapter which is leading to NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578154/unable-to-initialize-adaptersapi-object-in-mobilefirst-v8-0-adapter-which-is-lea)

- the Security check class does not allowed AdapterAPI.

My Next Solutions also does not work :

I have created new class and I called the object to get data, still it retun null values.

```
ServiceEmpImp testService = new ServiceEmpImp();

JSONObject objectJson= testService.validateAuthenticationfromService(dataAuth);
```

Any others solutions that work fine?

Answer (score 1):

While security checks are implemented within adapters, the MobileFirst security-framework and adapter APIs are separate and cannot be mixed. Therefore, you cannot use an adapter API, such as the AdpatersAPI interface, in your security-check code, and you cannot use security-check APIs in adapter resource code.

Please refer https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/creating-a-security-check/
for details on implementing security check and developing adapters.